# Placement of inducer for gas hot water tank

Tags: hot-water, exhaust-vent

My sister has lived in her house about 3 years, inspection was fine and no issues since. Hot water tank started leaking, the installer for the new one says that the inducer with double wall b venting is incorrectly placed, because the HWT and furnace vents tie together, then the inducer is next in line. He says he can't fix it, is only a plumber not HVAC, but the inducer should be before the furnace and HWT vents come together. CO detector across the room has never gone off. Opinions appreciated.

[image: Inducer is on the right side of photo]

[image: Inducer on left edge of photo]

Comment: There should be a wire that runs from the burner controller on the water heater to the control box for the draft inducer. Is there?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the picture below, if the air flow and identities of everything in the picture is correct, then it looks fine.

[image]

Comment: I'm only going by what my sister told me but yes, your labeling is correct (that's the inducer, whatever type it is) That inducer lists a company and says "Draft Inducer, Model D-3" on it.

Comment: @user20127 Yeah, the installation is perfectly good. And, if it was installed between the HWT and the fork, then it would be a problem because it could force air back toward the furnace.

Comment: Looks like it is on the output side to me + Ben

Comment: OP here: I believe this is the inducer my sister has: https://www.amazon.com/Tjernlund-D-3-Inducer-Vertical-Systems/dp/B000LDPUNI

Comment: @user20127 yes, that's a very common style of draft inducer.